# Vertex slide past edge limit?

Tags: modeling

The first *Vertex Slide* tool took an additional click, but you could push the vertex beyond the end of the edge. Is there a setting or method to achieve that with 2.68?

The old method of placing the cursor at the opposite vertex and scale away from it is wonderfully nostalgic, but a bit time consuming.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes, by using the **Clamp** setting.

Access by holding <kbd>Alt</kbd>, or toggle with <kbd>C</kbd>. This allows you to slide past the (0-1) limit and also prevents switching to slide along other edges then the ones currently selected.

This information is available in the header text during vertex slide.

Comment: Just wonderful. That's how a tool should feel. I must admit that I hardly ever look in the header when the action is somewhere else.