# Is it possible to slide an edge beyond the two vertices its attached to?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices, edges

[image: Here's a photo for reference]

Hey guys!

I got a simple, hollow circle mesh that I'd like to gradually fill by using edge slide. Meaning that I want to be able to slide the edge from the top to the bottom of the circle

The only problem is that I can only slide an edge in the space between the two vertices the edge is in between...or maye the vertices won't go past the other vertices, thus preventing the edge from sliding further. I'd like to slide beyond those vertices. Does anyone here know if it's possible to do that?

I'm very new to this, but I'm willing to learn and I would appreciate any helpful comments. :)

Comment: Do you require that this be done using a mesh object? Could it be a curve object instead? If you tell us what the desired end result is, we can think outside the box a little more when brainstorming solutions. Depending on what you want to do there may be a suitable solution of a totally different nature.

Comment: I don't understand this question either.

Comment: Sliding beyond edge limits is possible, if this is the question, then it's a duplicate of [Vertex slide past edge limit?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2981/15265)

Answer (score 1):

Not as far as I know. If this is for an animation, have a look at booleans: https://www.blender.org/manual/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

They are implemented as a modifier, so you could have a hidden (hide it from the outliner by disabling it's render) circle (or rather a cylinder) acting as a "stencil" and then a plane that gradually grows in width. This plane would have the modifier set as "intersect" on it. This would make the plane only show in places that are inside the cylinder, thus creating an effect of the plane filling the circle.

Answer (score 0):

If your effect need discrete steps, there is a way to do what you need, but not sliding edges: it works building the circle in horizontal stripes, and using a "build" modifier. It could be not perfect, but could fit your need somehow, so I try anyway:

[image]

here are some steps (at frames 1,11,41,81) :
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Just to give you another idea...

Answer (score 0):

@user277143's suggestion of using booleans would work.

Depending on you needs you could simply leave the circle whole. Then use a masking object, and just animate it moving out of the way.

You just need to have some understanding of 'Render Layers'.

The workflow would be: set up your scene normally, but reserve 2 working layers. One layer for the object being masked, and another layer for the mask itself. Setup 2 render layers, one for everything, and one for the masked objects. Then composite the layers together for final output.

In the example, layer 9 is the object being masked, a cylinder. Layer 19 is used for the mask, in this case, just a plane.
The plane is moved out of the way, to reveal the cylinder in the rest of the scene.

[image: masking setup]

There are 2 Render Layers, 'MaskedObjects' which renders the scene with the mask in effect. And 'AllOtherObjects' which renders everything normally *except* the mask and masked objects.

The result of compositing them together:

[image: masking 1]

[image: masking 2]

[image: masking 3]

Just another way of doing things. Here is the file above:

[image]